# How to use awk/sed to replace the specific line's value instead of whole line.

Tags: shell, awk, sed

```
cat phpmyadmin/config.inc.php | grep 'blowfish_secret'
```

Return value = **$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'A-wImn{Ax[K5F7MQg.2Uh6D1ICU:C0fe';**

```
grep 'blowfish_secret' config.php | awk -F "'" '{print $4}'
```

Return value = **A-wImn{Ax[K5F7MQg.2Uh6D1ICU:C0fe**

```
grep -n "blowfish_secret" phpmyadmin/config.inc.php | cut -d: -f 1
```

Return value = **17**

My goal is replace line 17' value "A-wImn{Ax[K5F7MQg.2Uh6D1ICU:C0fe" to "my_random_string" without replacing whole line. Is there a way to achieve that?

Will appreciate  any suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Try awk:

```
awk -v repl="my_random_string" '
    BEGIN {FS = OFS = "\047"}
    $2 == "blowfish_secret" {$4 = repl}
    1
' config.file
```

Using single quote as the field separator, if the 2nd field is the right key, replace the 4th field. `"\047"` in awk is a string containing one character, a single quote.

To write the new contents back to the original: pick one of

```
awk -v ... config.file > tempfile && mv tempfile config.file
awk -v ... config.file | sponge config.file   # from the 'moreutils' package
gawk -i inplace -v ... config.file
```

Comment: `OFS` not specified, will be defaulted to space.